# php show variable that belongs to a username

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the variable "points" which belongs to a certain username,.

This is a part of my login2.php file:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $points = $mysqli->query("SELECT points FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$username."'");

}
```

I dont know how to show the points now. I know that the outcome of $points is not the amount of points that belongs to a username. I actually want to know how to do this and what the outcome is of the $points. How can I show the **actual** result of the query I am running?(which would be the amount of points stored in my database So of course if you would run this query in mysql then the outcome will be :"Amount of points", but in this situation I dont know how to show the amount of points actually.

Comment: `$username = $_SESSION['username']` should come BEFORE the `mysqli_query`

Comment: @BeatAlex Yeah ok, but i still don't know how to show the result of the select query

Comment: echo "The points of $username are $points.";

Comment: You don't need to concatenate the string; *"select points from account_information where username='$username'" will still work perfectly* . Also, there's nothing special between that query and any other query; just check if the number of rows is greater than zero and loop through the result.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD but echoing the result wont work. I get an error.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Stop. Just stop. He's already doing this wrong by not preparing queries and binding variables (which you STILL have to do - you can't just change `mysql_query` to `$mysqli->query` and expect everything to be safe) - don't teach him even more bad habbits.

Comment: @h2ooooooo; I'm not teaching him a good or bad habit. Just letting him know that concatenating isn't necessary in that context. As for him not using PDO or prepared statements, I would have mentioned it if I wrote an actual answer.

Comment: He should start by learning the habbit of checking the documentation, this question is solved in the docs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($points)) {
    echo $row['points'];
}
```

Just put the results into an array called $row then access the parts of the array with $row['points'].

Comment: Why mix object and procedural style? What if we have several database connections?

Answer (score 3):

The "points" value is in, after executing AND FETCHING the sql/results.

Fetch row
http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

```
$sql_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT points FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$username."'");

while ($data_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($points)) {
    print 'Your score is: '.$data_row['points'];
}
```

Comment: So to show this I should echo it like this: echo "hello".$points['points'].""; ? It gives me an error:  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\Users\Loko\Desktop\Loko\school\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\login2.php on line 30

Comment: @djot I got an error after I tried this: Undefined index: points in login2.php on line 22 which is the 3rd line of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

OP already has accepted an answer but they **both arent good imo**. **NDM said it**, *take a look into the docs it's all well written there*.

I think it's also **very bad practice to mix object and procedural style**.

Also, the other answers **don't care about security**. Use prepared statements and reselect the username, because mysqli validates your `$_SESSION['username']` in this case.

Take a look into this one:

```
<?php
// Init the database connection
$db = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

// Look for errors or throw an exception
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    throw new Exception($db->connect_error, $db->connect_errno);
}

// Init prepared statement
$prep = $db->stmt_init();

// Prepared statement
$prep = $db->prepare("SELECT username, points FROM account_information WHERE username = ? AND username IS NOT NULL AND username != ''");

// See if statement is ok
if (!$prep) {
    throw new Exception($db->error);
}

// Put your variables into the query
$prep->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);

// Fire the query!
$prep->execute();

// This is magic, it's awesome.. try it :-))
$prep->bind_result($username, $points);

// Get the results easily
while ($prep->fetch()) {
    echo "{$username} has {$points}<br>", PHP_EOL;
}

// This is like in our house, when we leave it, we close the door
$prep->close();
$db->close();
```

**Update:**

Answering your comment, this style is better because objects are better in general than procedural functions. Better to program, better to read, **easier to understand** (object abstract from real life objects).
`bind_param` **validates your input**. Imagine me putting in `;DROP TABLE account_information;--` into my username session. This is **SQL Injection** - the only safe way to prevent them is to **`prepare` statements**. Or Imagine having **more than one database connection**. Every mysqli object represents a different connection. This is not as clear as with procedural style. Also, **error reporting** using Exceptions is way more flexible because they can be `catch`ed and `throw`n.

If you want to know more **about their returns**, just **read the manual**: http://php.net/mysqli_query

`mysqli_query / mysqli::query` return values:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but I would rather want to know what it exactly does. Like in my question I ask: What is the result of just:" $points = $mysqli->query("SELECT points FROM account_information WHERE username = '".$username."'");" Like I would want to know where to put everything and WHY it's better than the others.